# How do I generate numbers for discrete uniform distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics

How do I generate numbers for discrete uniform distribution in R. I need n =100 with the interval of [1,10]. In a simple way, I need number 1 until 10 **but the frequency of each number must be 10.** NOTE : The number must be an integer number.

Comment: Try `runif(100,1,10)`

Comment: I need an integer number.

Comment: Try `round(runif(100,1,10),0)`

Comment: The frequency of each number it's not equal. I need each of the numbers to have the same frequency. Please help me.

Comment: Try this: `sample(unlist(lapply(1:10, function(x) rep(x,10))),100,replace = F)`

Comment: I think this will do: `sample(rep(1:10, each=10))`

Comment: Thank you both!! Now, I get what i want. :)

Comment: please include the correct answer as an answer below to ease future reference.

Comment: sample(rep(1:10, each=10)) this one is the correct answer